# Android simple mp3 playback

Tags: android, html, media-player

I'm building an **Android** app using **Dreamweaver** and I want to have audio.

I made an index.html and put this script in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("a");
    if (button.addEventListener) {
      button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        mp.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.hound).start();
      }, false);
    }
  }
</script>
```

I put hound.mp3 in `/res/raw/`

And I put a button on the page:

```
<button id="a" value="click">play</button>
```

Then I exported the .apk and installed it on my phone, but the music doesn't play when I push the button. Am I missing something?

Comment: What JavaScript library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I switched to Java/XML because I'm finding out Eclipse is a better way to develop an app. THe sound problem I did fix, like this:

MainActivity.java:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.something);
         Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
         play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
         mp.start();
                }
            });
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/play_button" />
```

strings.xml:

```
   <string name="button_send">Play</string>
   <string name="play_button">Play</string>
```